# zf2 navigation inject page from controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2

In ZF2 it is possible to combine ( extend ) navigation item using both array and database ?

I have root navigation ( depth level 1 and 2 ) which config reside as an php file navigation.config.php. Now there is one page that base on product category that will create a navigation for each category with a child page.

```
module
\-submodule
   \-category 1
     \-add
     \-edit
     \-form
     \-list
   \- ...
   \-category n
```

It's tiresome to write everything as an array everytime I'm adding a category. Instead it will be good If I load it using code by reading the category from db than create a recursive mvc page for navigation.

All category actualy call same controller, but for UI sake I have to make it like above.

I test by creating a page using controller

```
public function listAction() {
    $this->addPages(
            array(
                array(
                    'label' => 'R12313',
                    'route' => 'home',
                    'pages' => array(
                        array(
                            'label' => 'R12313cccc',
                            'route' => 'home',
                        )
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'label' => 'R123132',
                    'route' => 'home',
                )
            )
    );
}

public function addPages($pages = array(), $min = 1, $max = 2) {
    $navigation = $this->services->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('navigation');
    $navigation = $navigation('navigation');

    $active = $navigation->findActive($navigation->getContainer(), $min, $max);
    if (isset($active['page'])) {
        $active = $active['page'];

        $pages = array('route' => 'home', 'pages' => $pages);

        $newpage = \Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage::factory($pages);
        $newpage->setDefaultRouter($this->services->get('router'));
        $active->addPages($newpage);
    }
}
```

It comes out nicely but then I unable to set the menu to active on click for itself and the parent.
Maybe doing it in Module bootstrap is better.

So any idea how ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is my workaround to add page from controller. Maybe there is a better way

```
public function addPages($id, $pages = array()) {
    $services = $this->getServiceLocator();

    $navigation = $services->get('viewhelpermanager')->get('navigation');
    $navigation = $navigation('navigation');

    $active = $navigation->findById($id);

    if ($active instanceof \Zend\Navigation\Page\AbstractPage) {
        $navigationFactory = new \Zend\Navigation\Service\ConstructedNavigationFactory($pages);
        $pages = $navigationFactory->getPages($services);

        $active->addPages($pages);
    }
}
```

You have to specify page id in the navigation.config.php though if you want to add it this way.